# Pulling object properties out of arrays and converting to string

Tags: arrays, string, jquery, object

I am currently working on a chat app and am stuck on getting properties out of an array of objects. I first sent an ajax request with json as the datatype. When I check my (data) parameter in my success function in the console it shows an Array called results which has 9 objects each with 4 properties in them. It looks like this, except each has a different id and text etc.

results: Array[10]
0: Object
createdAt: "2013-05-22T00:41:24.394Z"
objectId: "2tzXVBpwQA"
text: "SYSTEM: I'll be back."
updatedAt: "2013-05

I want to just pull out text: for each of the objects, however I have no clue how to do this. I've searched and used many methods like $grep and for statements to get text out to no avail(I am new to programming)

Here is the sample code

```
function newFetch(newDisplay){
    $.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats',
  data: null,
  success: function(data){
  /*alert('Load was performed.');*/
   var text = $.grep(data, function(e) { return e.text == text});
   newFetch(newDisplay(text));
  }
,
  dataType:"json"
});
};
```

NewDisplay in the callback is another function that appends the passed parameter to one of my .divs.

This code snippet so far seems to no grab the text but instead returns just [] when I use console. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

JSON.prase is your friend

```
 success: function(data){
    //...other success code you might want to run..
    var newObjArray = {};
    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
       newObjArray[i] = JSON.parse(data[i]);  
    }
 }
```

this should turn each entry in your array to an objects as well.

[JSON.Parse on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)